# Bot isn't responding to my function calls

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need my Discord bot to handle DM's and therefore I wrote this script:

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, user_id=None, *, args=None):
    if user_id != None and args != None:
        try:
            target = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
            await target.send(args)

            await ctx.channel.send("'" + args + "' sent to: " + target.name)

        except:
            await ctx.channel.send("Couldn't dm the given user.")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("You didn't provide a user's id and/or a message.")
```

My problem now is, until this point in my project I was satisfied by coding if-else-branches into the "on_message()"-function in order to make my bot react to certain commands but now my bot isn't reacting to function calls: When I try to call the "dm"-function (my command prefix is set to ".") it doesn't throw an error in the console it just doesn't work and I'm clueless to what I'm doing wrong here.

Is the code snippet not located in the right place inside my script? What am I missing?

I'd be glad for any form of help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs, you need to add a `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of your `on_message` listener.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Edit: Separate question but as I wrote in the comment, here's an example on DM'ing people on a certain time:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(hours=24*7)
async def dm_loop():
    user_ids = (123, 456, 789)
    for i in user_ids:
        user = await client.fetch_user(i)
        await user.send("hello")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    dm_loop.start() #remember to add this to your on_ready event
```

This would make it run on startup and then once a week.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Is there any possibility for the bot to dm users without someone having to manually do the request? I'm imagining my script having a list of discord id's and then I'd like to message them, let's say once a week. I might do a separate question if you can't help me out here, thanks :)))

Comment: @banachtarski do not do stuff on `on_ready`, it may crash your bot upon launching.
Instead use [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#recipes).